# Section latex before landscape

Tags: spacing, landscape

I want to add a landscape page between 2 pages, But the problem is that latex make a space before landscape, how to remove the section (which circled on red ) to the page 1.
the code is like that

```
Text 

\afterpage{
\begin{landscape} 
a

\end{landscape}
}

\Section 
Another text
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See if the  `afterpage` package can help you.

Comment: I used afterpage  but it still the same problem

Comment: Please give us a MWE.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Can you provide a `MWE` of your code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, also try with `\begin{sideways}` from the package `rotating` instead of `landscape`

Answer (score 1):

With only a chunk of code, someone can guess (but never be sure of) the packages used for enviroment and the `\afterpage` command, but what the hell is `\Section` without argument?. Please always supply a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) compilable as is, so that anyone can reproduce the issue without having to guess what you are really doing.

Said that, the issue seem to be you are placing the `\afterpage`command within the text of the first column, but at some effects the columns are regarded by LaTeX as pages (for instance,  `\newpage` in the first column start the second column, not the second page). Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\afterpage{\begin{landscape} x \end{landscape}}
\section{Another text}
\lipsum[5-10]
\end{document}
```

This reproduces the issue,  but replacing `\lipsum[1-4]` by `\lipsum[1-5]` (i.e., adding some more dummy text before `\afterpage`) solve the problem, since then `\afterpage` will be loaded in the second column.  Obviously, in the real document you <strike>cannot</strike>  should not add dummy text, but place `\afterpage` a bit later, even if this mean place it after the next section title:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{Another text}
\lipsum[5-6]
\afterpage{\begin{landscape} x \end{landscape}}
\lipsum[7-10]
\end{document}
```