# Whitespace before landscape in twocolumn pages (\afterpage does not work)

Tags: rotating, landscape, afterpage

How can I eliminate whitespace before a landscape page? \afterpage does not work for me. Please find below an example.[image]

My code is like that :

```
Text 

\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
```

Text1

```
\end{landscape}
```

a
}

```
\Section {head text2 }
Another text
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424744/how-to-remove-white-space-after-the-command-twocolumn/424822?r=SearchResults&s=3|10.1861#424822

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/564601/35864

Comment: afterpage package clearly documents that it does not support twocolumn. Just move the landscape environment later in the document after the text to fill the second column.